# Keyboard map is incorrect when using an NX-client

Tags: keyboard, client, nx

I have a problem with nomachine NX-client in Ubuntu. It seems that the keymapping has a problem. For example, the arrow keys do not work (except for up key which opens printscreen!). I searched online and found several solutions. However none of them worked for me:

#### solution 1)

On the server, change System->Preferences->Keyboard->Layouts to “Evdev-managed keyboard”

The server that I log into has Centos 5.7 on it and I cannot find “Evdev-managed keyboard” layout in keyboard setting. I tried several other generic keyboard layouts with no success.

#### solution 2)

add the following lines to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
EndSection
```

I did it and my keyboard stopped working completely! I had to use the on-screen keyboard to remove this setting and get back to normal.

#### solution 3)

Run `xmodmap -pke > localxmodmap` locally

Copy the file to server as `.Xmodmap`

Run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from terminal.

which gives me a bunch of errors such as:

```
xmodmap:  /home/fzc23/.Xmodmap:60:  bad keysym name 'XF86Switch_VT_1' in keysym list
```

and doesn't work.

I do not know what else to do. I would appreciate if somebody could help me out.

BTW, the NX-client on windows connects to the same server with no keymapping problem so I believe this is a problem in Ubuntu and has nothing to do with the server side.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem under Gentoo.  I can't promise that this will work on a CentOS 5 server, but this worked for me on a Gentoo server.

Inside your nx session, open a terminal window and run:

```
setxkbmap -model evdev -layout us
```

Replacing "us" with your desired layout if it isn't the US layout.  Your keymap should be correct now.  If you start your nx session using an .xsession/.xinitrc style script, you can add the setxkbmap command to the startup script.

Comment: NX broke for me on both Windows and Linux clients after installing newer versions of xorg with evdev keyboard drivers, but this command fixes it whenever I log on or resume a session.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going to **Preferences** → **Keyboard Shortcuts** and selecting **Desktop** → **Take a screenshot**.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

The setting there showed (seemingly correct) <kbd>Print</kbd>. However, I removed it by clicking the entry and then hitting backspace, changings it to **Disabled**. After that my cursor up key worked again.